# replacing all alphabetical character using regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying a replace all the alphabetical character of the randomly picked element from the books array with the "-" character using a regex. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong

```
<?php
 $books = array("Dune <br/> ~Frank Herbert", 
 "Romeo & Juliet <br/> ~William Shakespeare",
 "Sherlock Holmes <br /> ~Sir Arthur Conan Doyle",
 "The Iliad <br/> ~Homer");

  $randNum = array_rand($books, 1);
  $pattern = '[A-Za-z]';
  echo preg_replace($pattern, '-', $books[$randNum]);
?>
```

Comment: Regexp needs delimiters: `$pattern = '/[A-Za-z]/';`

Comment: Please always make a note of what output you _do_ get beside what you expect to get. But what is clearly missing here are the PCRE delimiters on your pattern `/[A-Za-z]/`

Comment: Make sure you have `display_errors` turned on, always when developing code. PHP would be complaining about this. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Thank you and sorry i didn't know it was such a stupid question till i saw your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your code try this will work-

```
      <?php 

      $books = array("Dune <br/> ~Frank Herbert", 
     "Romeo & Juliet <br/> ~William Shakespeare",
     "Sherlock Holmes <br /> ~Sir Arthur Conan Doyle",
     "The Iliad <br/> ~Homer");

     $randNum = array_rand($books, 1);
     $pattern = '/[A-Za-z]/';
     echo preg_replace($pattern, '-', $books[$randNum]);
    ?>
```